# Creating an outputstream of image in a servlet. How to display it on receiving

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am creating an image file on the server and without saving it, returning it directly as an output stream in servlet response. Upon receiving, how to display it in a jsp div. Please ensure that my page is not changed when i click on a button for servlet call and the image is displayed in a div on the same page.
The code that i have used for creating stream is as follows

```
package com.newgen.servlet.barcode;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class BarCodeGenerate extends HttpServlet {

/**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7027812863334578584L;
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //System.out.println("anand singh");
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    OutputStream out1 = response.getOutputStream();
    File file1;
    //PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try{
        int width, height;
        //String FileName = pInvoiceNumber + "."+ pFileExtn;
        //saveFile=new File(FileName);
        String pFontFilePath="E:\\Code128.ttf";
        String pBarcode=request.getParameter("barcodevalue");
        System.out.println(pBarcode);
        String format=new String("bmp");
        //BufferedImage bi,biFiltered;
        width=770;
        height=220;
        BufferedImage bufimg =new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics graphicsobj = bufimg.createGraphics();

        file1=new File(pFontFilePath);
        System.out.println(file1.exists());
        FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(file1);
        Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,fin);
        Font font1 = font.deriveFont(46f);
        graphicsobj.setFont(font1);
        graphicsobj.setFont(Font.getFont("3 of 9 Barcode"));  //3 of 9 Barcode
        graphicsobj.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        graphicsobj.fillRect(1,1,768,218);
        graphicsobj.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        ((Graphics2D)graphicsobj).drawString("*"+pBarcode+"*",25,170);
        ImageIO.write(bufimg,format,out1);
    }catch (Exception e){

    //out.println(e.getMessage());  
    }
}
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request,response);
}

}
```

Please suggest possible ways to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can already get the image in the browser by directing calling the servlet URL then all you have to do is put an img tag and put the servlet URL in it's src attribute.

```
<div>
    <img src="http://host:port/contextName/servlet-url">
</div>
```

This will make a **GET** request to your server and display the downloaded content inside `<img>`.

Comment: I can't do this.. i have to send parameters to the servlet and also the servlet call is to be made on a button click. I am achieving the calling by using AJAX call.

Comment: You can do the same, parameters must be url parameters. AJAX is not used for downloading a file in a normal way. GET parameters should be appended to the URL and on click of the button assign the URL to img's src attribute.

Comment: Thanks @11thdimension. You gave me the idea to create an image dynamically on click of a button. Thanks once again.

Comment: Welcome, if it works, post your changes to the code in the edits.

Comment: The above code remains the same . On jsp i used create element attribute